# Is it possible to disable the mouse events on showing some progress is going on

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i am doing an application in `asp.net` where when i click on a button i will show an `image(loading image)` saying that `progress` is going on. At that time i would like to disable the mouse events completely, so that the user should not perform any operations with mouse. Is is possible to achieve this in `Web application` if so can any one tell how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

my personal preference would be to attach a javascript event which occurs on button click and puts a transparent overlay over the page while the load occurs. The overlay can catch click/move events and discard them.